# WordPress admin area search not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Currently I have an installation of WordPress that is running a plugin called [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/). When I search for posts inside a custom post type I get no results at all. The URL string looks correct:

```
&action=-1&m=0&seo_filter&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
```

But it returns nothing.

Additionally, when I remove `&action=-1`, the search results show up correctly. I have tried disabling the plugin and it works correctly, however I have other sites using the same plugin and searching works on these.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: have you checked version of plugin in both site?

Answer (score 2):

Read - [Yoast's guide](http://wordpress.org/plugins/map-cap/) on integrating Gravity Forms to realise the greatness of this plugin.

It has a paid limitation on assigning role capabilities to custom post types which can be partially fulfilled with http://wordpress.org/plugins/map-cap/

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best asking the plugin developer in the WP Support forum.

http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/types